# Vs code Quotes being formatted to new line causing file to be a string

Tags: vue.js, eslint, prettier

I'm trying to format my file but the quotes are being added to new lines & turning my file into a string. Is there a setting in prettier / vscode to not format a quote onto a new line or to ignore this quote turning the entire file into a string

For Example:

```
@click="
   createStudent();
   $emit('hide-modal');
   makeToast('success');
"
// anything below this quote on a new line will make the rest of the file appear as a string.
```

Eslint file:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
    'eslint:recommended'
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  rules: {
    quotes: [2, 'single', { avoidEscape: true, allowTemplateLiterals: true }],
    'prettier/prettier': [
      'warn',
      {
        singleQuote: true,
        semi: false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include semicolons at the end of each function call

```html
<button
  @click="
    call1();
    call2();
  "
>
  test me
</button>
```

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-68568526-example-1-ihe1v)

---

Another way (and what I would argue is a better way) to handle this would be to create a method that calls all three functions.

```html
<template>
    <button @click="blahBlahClickHandler"> press me </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods:{
        blahBlahClickHandler(){
            this.createStudent();
            this.$emit('hide-modal');
            this.makeToast('success');
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: When adding semi colons to the functions, It will still turn everything below the second `"` into a string